# R: Histogram of missing data

Tags: r, csv, time-series, histogram, missing-data

I have a CSV of sec-by-sec values, that looks like this:

```
"x","timestamp","value"
"1",2016-01-01 00:00:00,124
"2",2016-01-01 00:00:01,121
"3",2016-01-01 00:00:02,NA
"4",2016-01-01 00:00:03,NA
"5",2016-01-01 00:00:04,NA
"6",2016-01-01 00:00:05,123
"7",2016-01-01 00:00:06,122
"8",2016-01-01 00:00:07,124
"9",2016-01-01 00:00:08,NA
"10",2016-01-01 00:00:09,124
```

So there is some data missing and marked as `NA`. Now I want to make an histogram of the length of missing data blocks. In the given example it would mean to count how many missing data blocks have length of `1 sec (1)`, of `2 sec (0)`, of `3 sec (1)` and so on.

In my real life data set the bins/intervals would be a bit different, I think of these eight categories:

```
= 1 sec
2 to 5 sec
6 to 10 sec
11 to 30 sec 
31 to 300 sec 
301 to 3600 sec 
3600 to 86400 sec
> 86400 sec
```

So my idea was to let the R code run through all lines of the CSV and whenever it detects an `NA` value, to count the lines until it finds a real value again. The eight categories could be an integer variable that is counted up `+1` everytime a fitting block of `NA`-values is detected.

As a complete R-noob I just have no idea how to do that. Help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Use run length encoding. See the help for `?rle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there must be a timeseries solution, but to get you started (using set.seed to generate repeatable random values):

```
set.seed(42)

# Create some sample data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, 
                 timestamp = seq(from = Sys.time() - 99, to = Sys.time(), by = "secs"), 
                 value = sample(c(NA, 1:3), 100, replace = TRUE))

# Runs of identical data
runs <- rle(is.na(df$value))

# Those that are missing
missing <- which(runs$values)

# The end positions in the sequence that are missing
positions <- cumsum(runs$lengths)

# The start times
start <- df$timestamp[positions[missing] - runs$lengths[missing] + 1]
end <- df$timestamp[positions[missing]]

# Time difference
delta <- difftime(end, start, "seconds")

# Combine in a usable data.frame
output <- data.frame(StartRow = positions[missing] - runs$lengths[missing] + 1, 
                     EndRow = positions[missing],
                     StartTime = start, 
                     EndTime = end, 
                     Duration = delta)
```

Comment: Great, thank you! That produced a perfect vector to keep on working with :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful

```
temp <- rle(diff(c(0,cumsum(is.na(df1$value)))))
runs <- temp$lengths[temp$values==1]
table(cut(runs,breaks = c(0,1,5,10,30,300,3600,86400,Inf),right = T))
hist(runs,breaks = c(1,5,10,30,300,3600,86400))
```